# 'and' & 'or' in the same entry query

Tags: entry, query

I've been attempting to create an entry query that queries the same custom field twice.

Basically I want to check if a custom field is between 2 numbers OR if it is empty.
Currently I'm using this to determine if the field is in range

```
{fieldNumber: ['and', '>=' ~ InputLow, '<=' ~ InputHigh] }
```

I cannot for the life of me work out how to create an additional OR for `fieldNumber`in the same query.

I've looked into the Yii `orWhere` option, but it's separating them with an `AND` for some reason - I've tried the following as a test

```
{% set Query = craft.entries(queryParams) %}
{% set Query = Query.orWhere(['between', '`content`.`field_fieldNumber`', "#{1}", "#{300}" ]) %}
```

it produced the following SQL

```
 AND (`content`.`field_fieldNumber` BETWEEN 1 AND 300) AND ((`content`.`field_fieldNumber` >= '58') AND (`content`.`field_fieldNumber` <= '62'))...
```

Ultimately I want a query that will produce something like the below, but I cannot for the life of me work out how to do it.

```
 AND (`content`.`field_fieldNumber` = null) OR ((`content`.`field_fieldNumber` >= '58') AND (`content`.`field_fieldNumber` <= '62'))...
```

Has anyone got any ideas, or can anyone point me in the right direction?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out in a roundabout way.

`orWhere` is just an OR join on other `orWhere` statements.

this collection of orWhere statements is then AND joined to the query.

so in my example I needed to do the following

```
{% set Query = craft.entries(queryParams) %}
{% set Query = Query.orWhere(['between', '`content`.`field_fieldNumber`', "1", "300" ]) %}
{% set Query = Query.orWhere('`content`.`field_fieldNumber IS NULL') %}
```